# Draw programmatically an image on top of a layout

Tags: android, layout, canvas, overlay, draw

I have a problem and looking online I cannot find any solution to this.

I have an xml layout like the following (I have simplified it and I have reasons to format like this):

```
<Linear layout>
    <Linear layout>
        <ImageView>
        <ImageView>
    </Linear layout>
    <Linear layout>
        <ImageView>
        <ImageView>
    </Linear layout>
</Linear layout>
```

Now what I have to do if following a certain event I want to draw an image over 1 of the 4 ImageView codewise?

(I don't want to use the background+src trick to do the job)

Thank you in advance
any help will be appreciated

Francesco

EDIT:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        >
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="15"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imagebutton1"
            android:onClick="imagebutton1_code"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imagebutton2"
            android:onClick="imagebutton2_code"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        >
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="15"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imagebutton3"
            android:onClick="imagebutton3_code"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imagebutton4"
            android:onClick="imagebutton4_code"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="18"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In general my probelm is that I would like to have still the layout declared in xml and just put an image over it wherever I want codewise.

Thank you again

Comment: Do u want to draw any shape on imageview ?

Comment: Hi Jogendra, is a png image so the problem is that if i go for another imageview then I have to create another imageview put it in a RelativeLayout (which I don't have) and use the alignTop attribute but I don't know where to put the overlay imageview since it can overlay different ImageView..

I think the solution will be somethingh different..

Comment: could you post your entire layout(xml)

Comment: I have edited the post adding the whole layout.

Comment: View view = (View) findViewById(R.layout.current_layout); //the layout you set in `setContentView()`
LinearLayout picLL = new LinearLayout(CurrentActivity.this);
picLL.layout(0, 0, 100, 0);
picLL.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(1000, 60));
picLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
((ViewGroup) view).addView(picLL);

Answer (score 0):

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        >
    </LinearLayout>

Assign An id to LinearLayout

View v = new ImageView(getBaseContext());
 ImageView image; 
 image = new ImageView(v.getContext()); 
 image.setImageDrawable(v.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gameover));

LinearLayout linlayout = findViewById(R.layout.current_layout);
linlayout.addview(v);
```

Comment: Hi Jogendra and TY for the quick reply,
my point with this is that in this case since the overlay image should every time be applied to different image based on a event then I would need every time to add the view then remove it and add to another linear layout etc..also with Linear layout I'm afraif is not possible to have an overlay image..

I was thinking the solution will be more like a canvas to be drawn at certain coords and then make it reappear at another coords but I don't know how to do this without loosing my current layout..